# Case sensitive sorting (lexical sorting) not working PostgreSQL citext type

Tags: postgresql, collation

I want to perform search and sorting simultaneously for the `citext` type in PostgreSQL.

```
select name from employee ORDER BY name ASC;
```

For the above query I get the following sort order:

```
"Adam"
"balaji"
"Cartus"
"dalal"
"erfan"
"Eric"
"Focus"
"lucus"
```

Is there any way to sort in the below order:

```
"Adam"
"Cartus"
"Eric"
"Focus"
"balaji"
"dalal"
"erfan"
"lucus"
```

I am using postgres version  "PostgreSQL 9.4.10, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit".

Comment: If you need proper collation support, you should upgrade to Postgres 12 where you can achieve this with ICU collations. 9.4 will be out of support in 4 weeks anyway, so you should have an upgrade plan already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
ORDER BY name::text COLLATE "POSIX"
```

That will cast `name` to a case sensitive type and use the binary collation.